# start dataflow using .bat file?

Tags: apache-nifi

how to start the dataflow I created without accessing the apache nifi interface. Is it possible to trigger run by running a .bat file? I am new in apache nifi and somewhat clueless on the limitation of apache nifi

I saved the dataflow as a template and want to start it without accessing apache nifi interface

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to start a processor.

**Timer driven**

> This is the default mode. The Processor will be scheduled
>   to run on a regular interval. The interval at which the Processor is
>   run is defined by the 'Run Schedule' option (see below).

**CRON driven**

> When using the CRON driven scheduling mode, the Processor is scheduled
>   to run periodically, similar to the Timer driven scheduling mode.
>   However, the CRON driven mode provides significantly more flexibility
>   at the expense of increasing the complexity of the configuration. The
>   CRON driven scheduling value is a string of six required fields and
>   one optional field, each separated by a space.

**Event driven**

> When this mode is selected, the Processor will be triggered to run by
>   an event, and that event occurs when FlowFiles enter Connections
>   feeding this Processor. This mode is currently considered experimental
>   and is not supported by all Processors. When this mode is selected,
>   the 'Run Schedule' option is not configurable, as the Processor is not
>   triggered to run periodically but as the result of an event.
>   Additionally, this is the only mode for which the 'Concurrent Tasks'
>   option can be set to 0. In this case, the number of threads is limited
>   only by the size of the Event-Driven Thread Pool that the
>   administrator has configured.

You can read more about it in the [Scheduling part of the NiFi User Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#scheduling-tab).

If you specifically want to start a processor from a bat file, you can use cURL. For that your flow must start with either [ListenHTTP](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListenHTTP/) or [HandleHttpRequest](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.HandleHttpRequest/). E.g. if ListenHTTP listens on port 8089 and your NiFi instance is accessible via my-nifi-intance.com, then you will have a webhook like my-nifi-intance.com:8089/webhook that will initiate the flow.

Since you are asking a very basic question, I encourage you to start with reading the [**Apache NiFi User Guide**](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html).